# Column defination mismatch correction in different database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having this problem while archiving transaction table from source database to archive database on same server(SQL server).
Archive database having already table schema present in it, but problem is there is mismatch between some of definition in table structure. After long research I am able to fix column not exist in table but stuck while matching column definition between source and destination table. Say table table1 having column A having dataType `varchar(100)` but in archive database table column A having `bigint` dataType, other scenario having problem with nullable type, source table having not null dataType of column whereas destination table having null dataType for same column and wise-versa.

Finally I am able to manage to find alter script which match column definition from different database, here it is:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + db1.table_name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + db1.column_name + ' ' +
type_name(sc.user_type_ID) +
case when type_name(sc.user_type_ID) = 'varchar' then '(' + 
cast(sc.[max_length] as varchar(max)) + ') ' else ''end+
case when sc.Is_nullable = 1 then ' null' else ' not null' end
from Sys.columns sc
Inner Join ARCHIVE_database.information_schema.columns db1 On sc.Object_id = Object_id(db1.table_name) and sc.Name = db1.column_name
where sc.Is_nullable <> (case when db1.Is_nullable = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end)
or type_name(sc.system_type_id) <> db1.data_type
```

Please help me out to find out more scenario and better solution to overcome this issue.

Comment: Does the destination table have any data in it?

Comment: there isn't any error in script, I am expecting better way to do this or additional scenario for such situations

Comment: @ElectricLlama yes destination table might have data in it. But source table data actual value for destination table.

Comment: If a target column is numeric and the source is char then you have to do some kind of cleansing. If you just want to synchronise tables, just script out the source table and create a brand new one in the target. Don't mess about altering it